# Android Camera Saving Pictures in Portrait Mode

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I'm trying to use a camera in my app and I want to be able to use it in landscape and portrait mode. I'm having no difficulty creating pictures in landscape mode, but I haven't found a good way to save pictures in portrait mode.

When I want to make a picture in portrait mode I need to set the displayorientation to portrait first, like this:

```
switch (windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()) {
    case android.view.Surface.ROTATION_0:
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        break;
    case android.view.Surface.ROTATION_90:
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
        break;
    case android.view.Surface.ROTATION_180:
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(270);
        break;
    case android.view.Surface.ROTATION_270:
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
        break;
}
```

But then the picture is still saved in landscape mode. One solution I found was to change the rotation parameter of the camera like this:

```
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
    if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
    int rotation = 0;
    if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
    } else {  // back-facing camera
        rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
    }
    mParameters.setRotation(rotation);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it may just set the orientation in the EXIF header and not actually rotate the picture (which is the case with the device I'm using).

Another approach was rotating the actual data after the picture is taken like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
int w = bitmap.getWidth();
int h = bitmap.getHeight();
Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
mtx.postRotate(rotate);
bitmap=  Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
currentData = stream.toByteArray();
```

But this approach takes 10 seconds (which is too long) and while I could put this code in an AsyncTask, I need the data one to a few seconds later, so then I'd still need to wait.

So far I haven't found a better solution.

Comment: Write some NDK code to perform the image rotation.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have never used NDK and when I looked it up it was recommended to not use it unless you're doing really intensive stuff or if you are very familiar with C/C++ (I haven't used them ever). And while my problem has to do with performance, I feel like there should be another (better) way to do this. I'm also afraid that NDK might screw up some of my application.

Comment: "you're doing really intensive stuff" -- rotating a multi-megapixel image where you "need the data immediatly after" would qualify as "really intensive stuff".

Comment: @CommonsWare You're probably right about this being intense stuff, but I still believe there is a better solution (maybe something that makes the camera take the image vertically, so I don't need to rotate it). I wonder how other apps do it.

Comment: "I wonder how other apps do it" -- they either save it with the EXIF header or they rotate the image themselves, using Java or NDK code. I can't rule out the possibility of a RenderScript Compute option for rotation, but half the reason for using the NDK is that you are going to run out of heap space in Java and fail to do the rotation, from time to time. RenderScript may help with speed but does not help with memory consumption. When I eventually add this to my (current) camera library, I'm thinking of using [this code](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations).

Comment: How do you grab image from camera? Either by handling `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` or other way?

Comment: @barmaley I use the `android.hardware.Camera` class with a custom SurfaceView to display the preview

Comment: @CommonsWare "save it with the EXIF header" - I've override the rotation attribute in EXIF header but I'm wondering are there any issues with this way ? because most answers I found is about rotating the bitmap and only use EXIF to read rotation attribute instead of writing it back.

Comment: @NhatPham: The biggest problem is running out of heap space, if you are physically rotating the image. Simply setting the EXIF header may be insufficient, as is noted in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution that makes me still need to wait for a second or two, but that's fast enough for me.
It's a pretty simple fix, just use the Matrix.postRotate method, but change:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
```

to:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
```

For me this is a pretty good solution, especially because everywhere else I already used .jpg images so it didn't make much sense compressing the Bitmap to a .png anyway.